# Incompatible pointer types to NSString from NSDate Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert a date to a string to not get this Incompatible pointer types to NSString from NSDate Waring ..

Here it is where I get it always.

```
 cell.lblHistoryTimeStamp.text = title.timestamp;
```

Thanks for help and fast answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm operating on an assumption that `title.timestamp` is instance of `NSDate`. You can use `description` method:

```
cell.lblHistoryTimeStamp.text = [title.timestamp description];
```

But it will output ugly format. So you'd have to use `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-M-d"];
cell.lblHistoryTimeStamp.text = [df stringFromDate:title.timestamp];
```

Comment: Just a warning, date formatters are not cheap to create. If you intend to use this in, say, a table view with many cells, use a "global" date formatter that you reuse in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use NSDateFormatter to convert NSDate to NSString (assuming your timestamp is an NSDate instance):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timestamp];
```